# spring Service method could not be read when deployed the war in tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, war

I have developed a java spring application where i am using tomcat server for my local testing. I do not face any problem when i run my application locally but when i export the war and deploy it in my cloud environment the new service method which i have written "saveOpenTokSession" which is an interface could not be read. and below is the stack trace which i am getting while i call the service.please guide me if u have any idea on this

```
       org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Cannot access Hessian remote service at [http://localhost:80/RDOService/hessian/DoctorService
                    ]; nested exception is com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianServiceException: The service has no method named: saveOpenTokSession
    at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianClientInterceptor.convertHessianAccessException(HessianClientInterceptor.java:293)
    at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianClientInterceptor.invoke(HessianClientInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy305.saveOpenTokSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.medicom.rdo.servlet.handler.DoctorServiceHandler.saveOpenTokSession(DoctorServiceHandler.java:1230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.medicom.rdo.servlet.handler.HandlerUtil.processRequest(HandlerUtil.java:129)
    at com.medicom.rdo.servlet.handler.DoctorServiceHandler.processRequest(DoctorServiceHandler.java:149)
    at com.medicom.rdo.controller.DispatchController.doDispatch(DispatchController.java:478)
    at com.medicom.rdo.controller.DispatchController.doService(DispatchController.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor303.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        Caused by: com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianServiceException: The service has no method named: saveOpenTokSession
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.Hessian2Input.prepareFault(Hessian2Input.java:449)
    at com.caucho.hessian.io.Hessian2Input.readReply(Hessian2Input.java:386)
    at com.caucho.hessian.client.HessianProxy.invoke(HessianProxy.java:195)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy304.saveOpenTokSession(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianClientInterceptor.invoke(HessianClientInterceptor.java:248)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: `http://localhost:80` in the cloud?

Comment: yes we have local cloud environment where we test our application

Comment: In cloud rather than localhost it must have an address name which you should refer like http://<myapp>:80/

Comment: we are deploying our application as a war so it will consider as local host and also my rest of the services are working fine only the service which i mentioned is not working